# Select all categories and all subcategories (in each category)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables:

1) REPORT ( ID, CLIENT_ID, STOP_TIME )

2) REPORT_DETAILS ( ID, REPORT_ID, CLIENT_ID, PRODUCT_ID )

I need to select all pairs (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID) where STOP_TIME is the biggest.
BUT! There can be couple Reports for one Customer contains same Product and this is the point...

My idea (i don't wont you to do my homework...i need just advice, some direction where to look):

```
    WITH temp_table (client_id, product_id, report_id, stop_time) AS(  
        SELECT distinct(rd.CLIENT_ID), rd.REPORT_ID, rd.PRODUCT_ID, r.STOP_TIME
        FROM REPORT_DETAILS rd
            JOIN REPORT r
            ON (r.ID = rd.REPORT_ID)
    )
    SELECT client_id, product_id,stop_time...
```

where time is max? i dont know

Comment: CUSTOMER_ID = CLIENT_ID ?

Comment: Yes...sorry for that...its the same thing

Comment: Something like this : SELECT distinct(rd.CLIENT_ID), rd.REPORT_ID, rd.PRODUCT_ID, r.STOP_TIME
FROM REPORT_DETAILS rd
JOIN REPORT r ON (r.ID = rd.REPORT_ID)
WHERE STOP_TIME= (SELECT MAX(STOP_TIME) FROM REPORT as rd2 WHERE rd.id = rd2.id)

Comment: REPORT as rd2 WHERE rd.id = rd2.id   <--- it gives allways TRUE

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;WITH temp_table
 (client_id, product_id, report_id, stop_time)
 AS
(  
            SELECT distinct(rd.CLIENT_ID), rd.REPORT_ID, rd.PRODUCT_ID, MaXTime
            FROM REPORT_DETAILS rd

                INNER JOIN (SELECT ReportId,MAX(STOP_TIME)As MaXTime 
                        FROM REPORT
                GROUP BY ReportId) r
                ON r.ID = rd.REPORT_ID 
        )
        SELECT client_id, product_id,stop_time FROM temp_table
```

Comment: I don't see why do you keep his temp_table ?

Comment: i have modified mr.qbs given query as per his requirement...nothing to do with Temp_table